# Gitlab configured with SSH keys still asks for password

Tags: ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

I am trying to avoid typing the password every time I want to pull or push from a gitlab repository. Therefore I followed https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/ but still, now every time I want to pull something it still asks me to provide the password for my remote gitlab repository.
Any clue on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the SSH link for your repository? It is like: `git@gitlab.com:YOUR-USER/YOUR PROJECT.git`

Comment: How do I check this? Because I tried to type the `ssh -T git@gitlab.hostname.com` and it says "Welcome to gitlab Kim Nicoli". Therefore I guess he can find the right path to my remote, but I guess what you meant was something different isn't?

Comment: sorry, I just got what you meant! Yes I am using the SSH link! now, and actually it works! Thanks a lot and my apologize for taking your time with this silly issue! :)

Answer (score 0):

One can check, whether `ssh` or `https` is active, with

```
 git remote show origin
```